# How to compare 2 JSON response (array) in Postman

Tags: arrays, json, compare, postman, response

I have 2 api responses and want to compare only one of the column values 'logline'. How can I do it?

I have tried the following, but the Test Result is always Failed.

```
pm.test("status Check", function () {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    var resp_arr = jsonData.results[0].series[0].values;
    _.each(jsonData, (arrItem) => {
        pm.expect(arrItem.status).to.be.oneOf(resp_arr);
    })
});
```

Basically, I want to compare 2 JSON responses which are in array format and only the second column.

My API Response: Both response are in same format & structure

```
{
   "results":[
      {
         "statement_id":0,
         "series":[
            {
               "name":"process_log",
               "columns":[
                  "time",
                  "logline"
               ],
               "values":[
                  [
                     "2020-09-21T12:41:01.199552139Z",
                     "9/10/2020 15:57:31.073\t abc"
                  ],
                  [
                     "2020-09-21T12:41:01.199824076Z",
                     "9/10/2020 15:57:31.078\t xyz"
                  ]
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: You're executing two requests, one after the other, and after the second one, you want to compare the certain values of the responses?

Comment: If you are trying to compare two responses, then I assume you must pass the content which need to be checked from first response into a globalvariable, and read it from there after the second response came.